# Is there a low level TCP appender for log4net?

Tags: c#, tcp, dns, log4net, logstash

I've been using the [UDPAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.UdpAppender.html) to send logs to [logstash](http://logstash.net). I would like to be able to achieve failover of the logstash server through DNS.

Implicitly, the *UDPAppender* does not detect whether or not the remote UDP port is available, but even if it did, when I configure it with a DNS name for ***remoteAddress***, it is resolved to the ip address during initialization and recorded as an ip address in the ***RemoteAddresss*** property. I am aware of the [RemotingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RemotingAppender.html), but this doesn't seem to like logstash because the logstash TCP input isn't implementing the .NET remoting protocol, and it looks as though it will suffer the same problem of resolving the remote ip address through DNS at the initialization step only.

I'm considering implementing my own appender, by either wrapping the UDPAppender with a ping or copying the RemotingAppender by handling reconnection through the DNS name. Does anything like this already exist?

Comment: Looking for same. Any success Rob? Rob can you refer any article/blog post for logging with UDPApender/log4net and logstash.

Comment: I hacked this together that works for my uses, which is based on https://github.com/merchantwarehouse/syslog4net TcpAppender: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3WE7h9 - turns out you've got a choice about how to buffer and drop packets while not connected. It might be a bit over-aggressive on how it flushes DNS caches, but at least it works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [log4stash](https://github.com/urielha/log4stash)?.
 
It's a log4net appender which have few similar features like logstash and sends your logs right into Elasticsearch.
That way you will have one less "failure point" in the way to elasticsearch (no need to use logstash at all).

And if you want to stick to TCPAppender,
You can transfer the code of [UDPAppender](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Appender/UdpAppender.cs) into a tcp without too much effort.
I did it once but unfortunately I can't publish the code.

Answer (score -5):

I found this [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html), the UdpAppender is near the end

[SDK reference](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.UdpAppender.html)

UdpAppender

For full details see the SDK Reference entry: log4net.Appender.UdpAppender.

The following example shows how to configure the UdpAppender to send events to a RemoteAddress on the specified RemotePort.

```
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
    <localPort value="8080" />
    <remoteAddress value="224.0.0.1" />
    <remotePort value="8080" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: This answer links to the same UDPAppender mentioned in my question and doesn't address any of the DNS failover issues. Would down vote if I had the power.

Comment: Yup, I did give you the sample code for the UDP appender, since no code was provided it was hard to figure out at what point that wasn't working for you.  So if you could provide a sample code, so that I can help you. FYI, empty down vote threats aren't really the Stackover flow way of things. provide samples and what you have done so far is, this is not a site that does your work, but helps you when you are stuck somewhere.